# Nlog AutoFlushWrapper on top of BufferingWrapper with database target the logs in buffer are lost if application crashes/closes abnormally

Tags: .net, nlog

I am using `Nlog AutoFlushWrapper` on top of `AutoFlushWrapper` which has `database` target with `fallback` to `file` target, currently i have buffer size of `50` along with `flushtimeout` to 2 minutes but if the application crashes/closes abnormally then the logs in buffer aren't logged.

e.g Nlog has `10` logs in buffer and application crashes then those logs aren't flushed.

Can anyone help me in this?

Here is the small snippet of the code

```xml
<target name="main" xsi:type="AutoFlushWrapper" asyncFlush="true" OptimizeBufferReuse="true">
  <target name="database_buffer" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="50" flushTimeout="120000" OptimizeBufferReuse="true">
    <target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" name="String" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
      <target xsi:type="Database" name="database_inner" connectionString="${event-context:item=dbConnectionString}"
              commandText="INSERT INTO [Log] ([Level],[Message],[Application],[MethodInfo],[Exception]) VALUES(@Level,@Message,@ApplicationName,@MethodInfo,@Exception)">
        <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level:uppercase=true}"/>
        <parameter name="@Message" layout="${event-context:item=Message}"/>
        <parameter name="@ApplicationName" layout="${event-context:item=SourceName}"/>
        <parameter name="@MethodInfo" layout="${event-context:item=MethodInfo}"/>
        <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${event-context:item=Exception}"/>
      </target>
      <target xsi:type="File"
              name="fallback"
              fileName="${basedir}Logs\Log.log"
              archiveAboveSize="10485760"
              archiveFileName="${basedir}\Logs\Archive\Log_{####}.log"
              archiveNumbering="Sequence"
              concurrentWrites ="false"
              maxArchiveFiles ="10"
              layout="Date: ${longdate}${newline}
          ApplicationName: ${event-context:item=SourceName}${newline}
          Level: ${level:uppercase=true}${newline}
          MethodInfo: ${event-context:item=MethodInfo}${newline}
          Message: ${event-context:item=Message}${newline}
          Exception: ${event-context:item=Exception}${newline}${newline}" />
    </target>
  </target>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the application crashes/closes abnormally then the logs in buffer aren't logged.

Sounds a bit unwanted to let the program crash itself, but it would recommend a `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();` in the `finally`.

e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //do something
        }

        finally
        {
            // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
            NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant that if application crashes then the logs in buffer are lost, i want the NLogger to automatically log the logs in buffer if application crashes

i couldn't find any variable in settings for that

Comment: There are not lost of you call shutdown. Of course nobody could run code after your program crashes.

Comment: Ok 
By the way I used LogManager.Flush() which flushes any pending logs , this can be used in cases such as 
WindowsService's Stop function etc

Comment: NLog.LogManager.Shutdown() = Flush with more cleanup. It's the more recommend in case of shutdown